ModalBottomSheet with images from the gallery
I want to make a UI (like in Telegram app) in my Flutter application so that when you click on the add image button, a ModalBottomSheet opens where images from the gallery are displayed. It should also be possible to turn on the camera. Which package can be used for this task?


Use photo_manager plugin for that.
